# Spring Batch Job Regression Testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, automation, automated-tests, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch job and test automation. We have implemented spring batch job in our project. Consider there are two applications - Spring batch application and Test automation application.

The Spring batch application, reads a file, do some validations and update values into DB.

Our test application is build with Java,Maven,Cucumber and TestNG. Cucumber is integrated with TestNG framework.

The flow is Cucumber features->StepDefinition->Page Object(Java class)->Access DB.
We have created test scenarios to test the spring batch job. The input file is different for each test scenario.
Test cases are developed to run in local environment.

Currently we execute test cases as follows:

- First execute Spring Batch application with a input file-the values are updated in DB
- Then execute test scenario in test application with same input file, which compares the value in input file with value in DB.(Spring Batch job and test cases are configured to access the same DB). This will validate if the data in input file is updated in DB.
- This is repeated for all test cases with different input file each time.

Each time the spring batch job is executed manually.

I did some research on spring batch testing and I found almost all the approaches are either based on Unit test or End-to-End test within the same spring batch application, which launches batch job for testing with JobLauncherTestUtils.

Is there a way to execute a spring batch job from another application(here the test application)to test its functionality?

What will be the best approach?

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: How is automating your manual approach fundamentally different from using `JobLauncherTestUtils`?

Comment: This approach seems convoluted IMO for no real added value. You can write a parametrized test class for your job (the parameter being the input file to test different scenarios) and yet still automate it. I see no need to create a separate app to automate tests. But to answer your question, you can use a `JobLauncher`/`JobOperator` or the `CommandLineJobRunner` to run your spring batch job.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje If I understand your question correctly, Since we are executing the spring batch application manually for each test, I could say our approach is not fully automated. The test application is not built with spring framework so I am trying to explore other options than utilizing JobLauncherTestUtils

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes this approach seems to be complicated without using SpringFramework. I will try to implement the parameterized test class. Thanks for your suggestion.